# When argument set 'safe=True' performances drop mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the following code:

```
dbh.postings.update({"word" : word},{"$pushAll":{"postings":self.postings[word]}}, safe=True, upsert=True)
```

Comparison of performances:

Insert/Update on 3060 rows (word -> postings)

- With 'safe' set on True: 3.7s
- Without 'safe' set on True: 0.4s

How is this possible? Why operations with the parameter 'safe' set are so slow?

Structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("520d08f5c9aaeee8311e2e7c"), "postings" : [ [ 12, 1 ], [ 14, 1 ] ], "word" : "95" }
```

Updates are made on: "postings" : `[ [ 12, 1 ], [ 14, 1 ] ]` where a field of  `[ 14, 1 ]` pair is added with $pushAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's expected.

Safe off means it only acknowledges the operation with the socket however, with safe on it will actually do relatively the same thing as SQL techs and make sure the operation actually went to MongoDb etc.

However, as for your update taking so long, we cannot tell without more information. for example indexes, document structure and arguments you are sending into that update statement.

Comment: I have added sample for the row structure.

Comment: @badc0re Do you have an index on `word`? How many postings combinations are you pushing? Is that a real sample of what your updating takng this long? The size of the postings array is vital to understanding timings

Comment: This is an inverse document index, for the question i don't have index on word and for the combinations depends on [document_id, word_frequency] pairs.

Comment: @badc0re ah you are attempting to build an fts index. You definitely need an index, it will slow writes but without it mon godb needs to read every document in the collection.

Comment: you mean i should creat index like dbh.postings.create_index("word") ?

Comment: @badc0re yes, create one on words since that is what your searching by

Comment: Yes, there is an improvement, 1.5s with safe set, thank you. :)